# Order I am checking strings getting wrong output

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, find

I'm new to c++ though I have basic knowledge of Java, I'm trying to make a program that converts roman numeral input and then finds the equivalent Arabic number and outputs it. However I am having an issue of finding how to great the correct order in finding specific prefixes in the roman numerals, for instance, since it is checking for "X" separately and deleting it; my program is translating the input "IX" as 11 when it is actually 9. I know this has to do with the order that my program finds the prefixes in the strings, however I'm not sure on how to fix it, so any help on that would be great.

Current code:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>



using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    string roman_digits [] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    string roman_tens [] = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    string roman_hundreds [] = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    string roman_thousands [] = {"", "M", "MM", "MMM"};
    string line, substr;

    int arabic = 0;


    // MCCCXXXVII

    cout << "Type in a Roman numeral: ";

    // Loops through inputted Roman Numerals.    
    while (cin >> line) {
        if (!cin.eof()) {
            int i = 0;

            // Loops through a Roman numeral and changes it to uppercase.
            while (line[i]) {
                char c;
                c = line[i];
                c = (toupper(c));
                line[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the thousands array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


                if (line.find("MMM") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("MMM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else if (line.find("MM") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("MM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else if (line.find("M") != string::npos) {
                    unsigned pos = line.find("M");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }
                if (roman_thousands[i] == substr){
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 1000);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the hundreds array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("CM") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CM");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("DCCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DCCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4);
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                } else  if (line.find("DCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("DC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("DC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("D") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("D");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                } else  if (line.find("CD") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CD");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("CCC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CCC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                }else  if (line.find("CC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("CC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("C") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("C");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }

                if (roman_hundreds[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 100);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the tens array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("XC") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XC");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("LXXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LXXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4);
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                }else  if (line.find("LXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("LX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("LX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("L") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("L");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }else  if (line.find("XL") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XL");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("XXX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XXX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);  
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                }else  if (line.find("XX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("XX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("X") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("X");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1); 
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                }


                if (roman_tens[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + (i * 10);

                }
            }
            // Loops through checking roman numeral with the digits array and if there is a match prints out the equivalent arabic number.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (line.find("IX") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("IX");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("VIII") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VIII");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 4); 
                    line.erase(pos, 4);
                } else  if (line.find("VII") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VII");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("VI") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("VI");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("V") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("V");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);
                    line.erase(pos, 1);
                } else  if (line.find("IV") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("IV");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                } else  if (line.find("III") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("III");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 3);
                    line.erase(pos, 3);
                } else  if (line.find("II") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("II");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 2);  
                    line.erase(pos, 2);
                }else  if (line.find("I") != string::npos){
                    unsigned pos = line.find("I");
                    substr = line.substr(pos, 1);                  
                }


                if (roman_digits[i] == substr) {
                    arabic = arabic + i;

                }
            }
            cout << "The Arabic equivalent of " << line << " is: " << arabic << endl;
            arabic = 0;
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid Roman numeral." << endl;
        }


    }
    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a greedy parsing strategy.  That is to say, consume as much of the input as you can, as long as you have a valid digit.  For example, with your example input:

```
MCCCXXXVII
```

First you look at the `M`,  which is a valid digit.  Then you look at `MC`, which is not a valid digit, so you consume the M, then start over at the `C`.

Is `C` a valid digit? Yes.  Is `CC` a valid digit? Yes. Is `CCC` a valid digit? Yes. Is `CCCX` a valid digit? No, so consume the `CCC` and start again at the `X`.

Get the picture?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't thought about it much, but it seems to me that the problem is simpler than what you are trying to make it... I believe you should be able to parse the string one character at a time updating the value.

The general idea would be that you start with the outcome set to 0 and read one character at a time while remembering the previous character (initially set to something that cannot appear in the input. For each character read, increment the value by the value of that character (M = 1000, D=500, C = 100,...)

The strange case comes when the last character read is of a lower denomination than this character. In this case you just need to fix the value.

For example, in MCD, you would start incrementing by 1000, then 100, then you find 500, but that is larger than C, so you need to fix: decrement the 100 that you added before, add 400 for a total of 1400.

Comment: That's good, and seems much more efficient than my idea.  Looking for test data.

Comment: Just for the sake of it I implemented the algorithm. 50 lines total in the cpp, including error reporting. The actual algorithm 16 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a debugger! Here's what I found:

- User types in `IX`
- Everything is fine until you get to your `for` loop that runs through your `tens` array:
- When you are looping through your `tens` array, there is a check for
  `else if (line.find("X") != string::npos)`
- It returns `true`. Is it supposed to? `9` should not be in `tens`.
- A solution to **one** of your problems would be to check whether it's not a `9`:

  `else  if (line.find("X") != string::npos && line != "IX")`

Edit:

This is only a quick hack, in the long term you should follow David Rodríguez's advice and simplify your solution.